# С++ Приведение объекта класса наследника к базовой части

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, класс

Что нужно изменить в этом коде, чтобы это заработало? K[i] - это Kaloda, нужно её както привести к типу IFormattable&

```
void prettyPrint(const IFormattable& object)
{
    cout << object->format();
}

void KolodasInfo()//Информация о колодах
{
    cout << "Колоды: \t";
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) prettyPrint(K[i]);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Классы:

```
class IFormattable
{
    public:
    
    virtual string format() {return "";}
};

class Koloda:IFormattable
{
    public:

    int size;

    virtual string format() {
        string str = "[";
        str.append(to_string(size));
        str.append("]");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум отойти немного от стиля C#. Укажите спецификатор класса `class Koloda:(спецификатор)IFormattable`

Comment: Ну, как минимум наследование должно быть `public`...

Comment: Harry, ну я так и решил этот вопрос. Я просто больше по сишарпу. Не знал об этом.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на все изменения по сравнению с вашим кодом (включая `const`, `.` вместо `->`...), и постарайтесь понять, почему они сделаны. Если уж совсем самостоятельно не получится — спрашивайте...

```
class IFormattable
{
    public:
    
    virtual string format() const {return "";}
};

class Koloda: public IFormattable
{
    public:

    int size;

    virtual string format() {
        string str = "[";
        str.append(to_string(size));
        str.append("]");
        return str;
    }
};


void prettyPrint(const IFormattable& object)
{
    cout << object.format();
}

void KolodasInfo()//Информация о колодах
{
    cout << "Колоды: \t";
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) prettyPrint(K[i]);
    cout << endl;
}
```